# Javascript parse JSON with stringify neested object

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, nested

I'm trying to parse a json object that an application (AWS lambda) wrote in a log file, but this json has an stringify object nested. Something like that:

```
input = '{"object":"{\"base\":\"brn\",\"scope\":\"all\",\"channel\":\"sve\",\"service\":\"getAssociatesCards\",\"entity\":\"consolidate\",\"attribute\":\"cRelId\",\"qualifier\":\"45430608\"}"}'
```

And when i try to parse it fails:

```
JSON.parse(input)
```

With this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token b in JSON at position 13
```

What can i do for fix this and get a nice Json Object?

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the definition of the JSON like in the code in your question, declare it with `String.raw` so the backslashes are interpreted as literal backslashes.

The inner `object` property contains more JSON, so you can parse that as well if you want:

```js
const input = String.raw`{"object":"{\"base\":\"brn\",\"scope\":\"all\",\"channel\":\"sve\",\"service\":\"getAssociatesCards\",\"entity\":\"consolidate\",\"attribute\":\"cRelId\",\"qualifier\":\"45430608\"}"}`;
const parsed = JSON.parse(input);
console.log(JSON.parse(parsed.object));
```

Comment: Hi, i haven't control over the definition of the JSON. I read the JSON from a file and i'm trying  to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading this from some log file and you cannot control how it is defined, you could always strip out the inner json and parse it on its own.

```js
var input = '{"object":"{\"base\":\"brn\",\"scope\":\"all\",\"channel\":\"sve\",\"service\":\"getAssociatesCards\",\"entity\":\"consolidate\",\"attribute\":\"cRelId\",\"qualifier\":\"45430608\"}"}';

var innerJSON = input.substring(11, input.length - 2);

console.log({
  object: JSON.parse(innerJSON)
});
```